# How to save a website as an app on OS X

Tags: macos

How do I export a website to an app in safari? There is this feature in iOS 7 called 'save to home screen', I'm looking for something similar on OS X.

Comment: The solution is natifier, check it here https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I've ever seen this done on OS X is via the [Fluid app](http://fluidapp.com/). Fluid is just a WebKit wrapper around a specific URL and without the browser navigation tidbits in the windowing. It presents the website as an "app" but it's still running in a browser window, albeit one with fewer decorations.

> Fluid lets you create a Real Mac App (or "Fluid App") out of any website or web application, effectively turning your favorite web apps into OS X desktop apps.

It's free to use but for $4.99 you can get some features that make it a little cooler. Most importantly you can get per-instance cookie stores so you don't cross-pollute your apps.

I used to use it for Fogbugz and it was alright. Not great, but decent. And I used to get all kinds of questions about the Fogbugz icon in my dock from my colleagues. It's still possible to click away from the main app in the Fluid-ized version of it, leaving you on an unintended web page with not a lot of nav options to get back to the main app. That was probably my biggest gripe with it.

Comment: Neat! I think Chrome is able to do something like this natively on Windows -- I wonder if feature parity for the mac version is on its way.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear if op is asking about iOS or OS X. Ian C answered for OS X. In iOS, AFIK all that's possible is to place an icon on the home screen, which is simply a shortcut to open the web page in Safari.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit, but from looking at the original title and the used tags I assume the OP is looking for an OSX solution.